# Return list using git diff and grep

Tags: bash, grep, files, git, diff

I'm using git diff to return the file names of files recently changed and i'm trying to pipe the returned file names into a grep expression that searches each file and returns the files that have "*.yml" in the file name and "- name:" in the actual file. However it seems like my code only returns all the files in the directory that match the conditions, basically ignoring the git diff.

```
files=($(git -C ${dir} diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD | grep -rlw --include="*.yml" --exclude-dir=$excluded_paths-e "- name:"))
```

Any help would appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the output of `git -C ${dir} diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD`, the output of the complete pipe `git -C ${dir} diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD | grep -rlw --include="*.yml" --exclude-dir=$excluded_paths-e "- name:"` and add the expected result. Make sure to copy&paste exactly the command you run on your system. Variable expansions should be quoted `--exclude-dir="$excluded_paths"` and there must be a space between this and `-e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git diff --name-only` produces a list of files; you need to give that list to `grep` in a form it will understand, *i.e.* as command-line arguments. One way to do this is

```
git -C "${dir}" diff -z --name-only HEAD^ HEAD | xargs -0 grep -lw --include="*.yml" --exclude-dir="$excluded_paths" -e "- name:"
```

I added `-z` so that the file names are separated by null bytes; the `-0` `xargs` option specifies the same delimiter for use in `xargs`’ input. I removed the `-r` option from `grep` — that is used for recursive searches, which is counter-productive here since the exact list of files to check is given.